# Is there any option to check if an android phone is idle for some specific time?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a requirement and for that, i have to check if an android phone is idle, i.e user didn't unlock the phone nor answered any call for some specific amount of time. Is there any way to check this condition?

Comment: Can't be anywhere near performance related. Removed the Performance tag.

Answer (score 1):

Monitor the `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts. If the `SCREEN_ON` broadcast is not sent for the time you want after a `SCREEN_OFF` broadcast, then the user hasn't used his phone for that amount of time.